# Bilinear interpolation on quadrilateral

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, bilinear-interpolation, quadrilaterals

I am interpolating data from the vertices of a quadrilateral to any random point inside the quadrilateral. I implement this by first doing a coordinate transformation which reshapes the quadrilateral to a unit square and then using bilinear interpolation.
Does any of the python libraries already have an implementation to do this?

Comment: If you are already "interpolating data", then you must have a solution. What more do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Bilinear interpolation between the corners of a quadrilateral gives the coordinates

```
P = (P00 (1-u) + P10 u) (1-v) + (P01 (1-u) + P11 u) v
  = P00 + (P10-P00) u + (P01-P00) v + (P11-P10-P01+P00) uv.
```

This forms a system of two quadratic equations in the unknowns `u`, `v`. If `P` is inside the quadrilateral, `u, v ε [0, 1]`.

If we take the dot and cross products with `P11-P10-P01+P0`, the system takes  the form

```
A + B u + C v + D uv = 0
a + b u + c v = 0
```

from which we eliminate `v` by

```
c (A + B u) - (C + D u) (a + b u) = -b D u² + (B c - b C - a D) u + (A c - a C) = 0
```

which is quadratic univariate. Compute the roots and keep the one in the domain. From `u` you get `v`.